# Installation Advice for Swimlane NGX Datatable

Tags: angular

I want to try Swimlane's ngx-datatable out on my Angular project but cannot seem to get it installed properly.

I am developing in Visual Studio 2015 and my simple project utilises Webpack which has a `webpack.config.vendor.js` file.

I first ran `npm install @swimlane/ngx-datatable@6.3.0 --save`. This added `"@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^6.3.0"` to my `package.json` file. I then added `'@swimlane/ngx-datatable'` to my vendor array in my `webpack.config.vendor.js` file. In my `app.module.ts` file I added `import { NgxDatatableModule } from "@swimlane/ngx-datatable";` and added `NgxDataTableModule` to the imports in the @NgModule declaration. From there I simply copied and pasted the simple example code from the Swimlane tutorial.

I re-packaged with webpack using `webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js` and checked the resulting `wwwroot/dist/vendor.js` file and the Swimlane code was in there.

When I debug I get the following error:

`Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Prerendering failed because of error: ReferenceError: document is not defined
at Object../src/utils/prefixes.ts (C:\Workspaces\FeaturePrototype_01\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:95264:46)`

Can anyone offer any advise please?

Comment: did you figure this out? I am also having the same issue.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't. In the end I completely changed my approach and am now using d3 v4 which is working really well.